# Pandas Data Frame for SP500 Joined Closes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am running this code in idle and I am getting nothing in my terminal.

```
import bs4 as bs

import datetime as dt

import seaborn as sns

import os


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import style

import pandas as pd

from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

from pandas import DataFrame

import pickle

import requests

import yfinance as yf

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Dell\Documents\python\joined closes\sp500_joined_closes.csv')
       
print(df.head())
```

Not sure what is happening, any advice?

Comment: Even not an exception like `IndentationError` or `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.